# I have duplicated from one cassandra container to a brand new cassandra container. (Same image, ver 3.11.5)

Tags: cassandra

The old Cassandra container was shut down abruptly and i have issues starting it up. I've copied the data over to another container and I getting the following issue,

1. I have tried using snapshots and restore. but the data wasn't correct.
2. Sadly the replicated node was facing some issues as well.
3. Currently, the new node is working but I am noticing this error.

How can I fix this error?

```
DataTracker.java:161 - SSTableIndex.open(column: search, minTerm:  , maxTerm: te mohamed tahir , minKey: a6497a9d-5b1f-4707-bbe3-be3a6ebaadcd, maxKey: a6497a9d-5b1f-4707-bbe3-be3a6ebaadcd, sstable: BigTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/pab/client-2a3c4e90bfe711eebc156d2c86545d91/md-13-big-Data.db'))

INFO  [CompactionExecutor:3] 2024-02-02 01:55:03,499 DataTracker.java:161 - SSTableIndex.open(column: search, minTerm:  , maxTerm: zza salim , minKey: 00057570f58f4a1eaf4b29af3802dbdd, maxKey: testclient11449, sstable: BigTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/pab/client-2a3c4e90bfe711eebc156d2c86545d91/md-12-big-Data.db'))

ERROR [CompactionExecutor:3] 2024-02-02 01:55:03,499 CassandraDaemon.java:228 - Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:3,1,main]

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Self-suppression not permitted
    at java.lang.Throwable.addSuppressed(Throwable.java:1072) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
```